# Check convergence using comparison test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was solving the questians of a book by savita,arora Mathematical Analysis. I was not able to  find which series must be used to compare the series

The questian is to test the convergence
1.$$\Sigma \frac{\sqrt{2n-1}}{(2n+2)(2n+4)}$$:
I used $\frac{1}{n}$.   to compare
My steps are.$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\Sigma \frac{\sqrt{2n-1}}{(2n+2)(2n+4)}} {\frac{1}{n} }=\frac{ \sqrt{2}}{4}$$.
So it is number not equal to zero. since  $$\frac{1}{n}$$ is not convergent thus is $$\Sigma \frac{\sqrt{2n-1}}{(2n+2)(2n+4)}$$ .But the answer key shows it is convergent.where am i wrong.if i am wrong how to correct it

2. $$\Sigma\frac{n+1}{n^p}$$ i compared it with  $$\frac{1}{n^p}$$  so by comparison test of first type it is convergent for $$p>1$$ but in the answer key the series is convergent for $p>2$
3. $$\Sigma\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\tan\frac{1}{n}$$ what series must be used to compare this

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question for information on how to attract quality answers. Better spelling and formatting will help you attract more attention.

Comment: Please fix formatting , if you use double dollar signs surronding your math it will look better

Comment: Using \sum rather than \Sigma will also help.

Comment: What type of comparison test (limit, direct) are you using?

Comment: First one using limit comparison

Comment: Could you fill in your steps for #1? I don't see how you reached $\sqrt{2}/4$ using a comparison with $\sum (1/n)$.

Comment: Your comparison was incorrect, look at my answer for why

Comment: Your first step is in error. With $f(n)$ being the nth term, we  have $f(n)/(1/n)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will help you on the first one.

We have:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{2n-1}}{(2n+2)(2n+4)}=\dfrac{n^{1/2}(2-1/n)^{1/2}}{n^2(2+2/n)(2+4/n)}$$

To find a good comparison, we must **factor** out the largest $n$ from both the numerator and denominator.

Now we see that the highest terms are $\dfrac{n^{1/2}}{n^2}=\dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}}$, and this is our $b_n$ (this was your mistake, you thought it was 1/n).

---

You evaluated the limit and got $\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$, thats good.

Notice that $\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4} \in [0, \infty)$, and so what this means is that **a_n and b_n behave the same!**

When you come up with a comparison like $1/n$, we are using the **limit comparison test**[image]

So since $b_n$ diverges, $a_n$ also diverges (this is what you thought),

but actually the $b_n$ was incorrect, and if you use the p-series test you see that $1/n^{3/2}$ converges, and so does our $a_n$ then.

Comment: It was very useful... with this trick i got that we must take $\frac{1}{n^{p-1}}$ so $ p-1>1 $ hence $p>2$

Answer (score 1):

For $n\in \mathbb N$ we have $0<\frac {\sqrt {2n-1}}{(2n+2)(2n+4)}<$ $\frac {\sqrt {2n}}{4n^2}=$ $\frac {\sqrt 2}{4}\frac {1}{n^{3/2}}.$